# User Input - What Do these 2 Lines Mean

Tags: c#, console

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter The Radius: ");

//"Console.ReadLine();" is what lets me write a number?
string radiusString = Console.ReadLine();

//This will grab the "radiusString" number I type and convert it into a number I can
//use for an equation? Because without converting it you can't actually add the number
//string to an equation because string is just text?
double radius = Convert.ToDouble(radiusString);
```

Alright so I know that it will allow me to input a number and it will convert it to a `double`, but which part allows me to write the number. Is it the `string` line? And does the `double` line just convert the `radiusString` to an actual number?

I'm trying to figure out the difference between `string` and `Console.WriteLine("text here")`. Doesn't a `string` mean a line of text in letter form just like `Console.WriteLine`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> alright so i know that it will allow me to input a number and it will convert it to a double, but which part allows me to write the number is it the `string` line?

Basically, yes. `Console.ReadLine()` is the actual call that waits for some input from the console (or takes the input that is already there) until the next input end of line. It then stores this data in the `radiusString` variable.

> and does the `double` line just convert the `radiusString` to an actual number.

Yes. It converts a textual representation of the number into an "actual" number that the computer can calculate with.

> im tryijng to figure out what the different between `string` and `console.writeline("text here")` doesn't a string mean a line of text in letter form just like `console.writeline`

`string` is a data type (or, in the usage you show here, more concretely, it declares a variable that can store data of type `string`). Data of type `string` is any amount of text, no matter how many lines.

The crucial fact to note is that a variable is not "a line that appears in the console". It holds some text that is in memory, ready to be used by your program. In order to *display* it or output it in any way for the user to see, you have to use a command such as `Console.WriteLine`.

Answer (score 0):

A bit unsure on your question. The `Convert.ToDouble(radiusString);` will convert the type you provided (`string`) into a `double`.

`Console.ReadLine` will await input from the console before proceeding.

`Console.WriteLine` will write a new line with the specified `string`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of reading ahead of you my friend, Id recommend a c# teach me book.  OK. so,

`Console.WriteLine("Enter The Radius")` writes something to your console, `Console.ReadLine()` reads a line of text.  If you didnt assign it to a variable, your typings are lost!

String defines a variable of type string, so it can contain "cat" "12.723719293" "{1,2,3,4}" its just characters.

The `Convert.ToDouble` does indeed make it a number, as otherwise you could be trying to say multiply "cat" by 5 ... so if you typed "cat" in your input it would fail to convert it to a Double..

Answer (score 0):

`Console.WriteLine();` allows you to write to the console.

`var text = Console.ReadLine();` allows you to read from the console into the text variable.

`var number = Convert.ToDouble(text);` changes a string to a double.